# enter the value in day of the week text field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario, where I need to send values in the text field. The values are, either 1 or 0 depending on current day of the week. In the scenario below, I need to enter '0' for the current day and '1' for the remaining days. I was hoping, since its Tuesday, I will get "0" in the Tuesday text field, but it showed 0 in all text fields. Below is my code starting from `sunday - tuesday`.

BTW : `id=w_1` is sunday, `w-2` is monday, `w_3` is Tuesday.

Thanks!

```
public String enter0And1(String daysOfWeek) {

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

WebElement sun = driver.findElement(By.id("w_1"));
    sun.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    sun.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);

    if(driver.findElement(By.id("w_1")).equals(currentDay)){
    sun.sendKeys(current_day_zero); 

    }
    else {
    sun.sendKeys(current_day_one);
    }



    WebElement mon = driver.findElement(By.id("w_2"));
    mon.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    mon.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);

    if(driver.findElement(By.id("w_2")).equals(currentDay)){
    mon.sendKeys(current_day_zero); 

    }
    else {
    mon.sendKeys(current_day_one);
    }


    WebElement tues = driver.findElement(By.id("w_3"));
    tues.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    tues.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);

    if(driver.findElement(By.id("w_3")).equals(currentDay)){
    tues.sendKeys(current_day_zero); 

    }
    else {
    tues.sendKeys(current_day_one);
    }

return daysOfWeek;



}
```

HTML for **Tuesday**:

```
<tr>
<td><div width="60%" class="form_label" id="w_3_label">
Tuesday
</div>
</td>
<td><input type="text" id="w_3" onchange="calculateAvgDI()" value="" size="9" maxlength="9" name="dailyWeightGoal(tuesday)">
</td>
```

Comment: Why did you do `driver.findElement` different for tuesday than the other 2 days?

Comment: oh, its because I grabbed Tuesday by its name. I have tried with the ID as well, but not luck.

Comment: can u share the html of any of the days?

Comment: @VivekSingh added HTML for Tuesday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that u r having is already pointed out by Alecxe. As an alternative can u try with this piece of code.

```
String day = new Date().toString().split(" ")[0]; //returns day of week as for eg. Wed
List<WebElement> days = driver.findElements(By
        .xpath("//input[contains(@name,'dailyWeightGoal')]")); // Will get list of all input elements
for (WebElement webElement : days) {
    if (webElement.getAttribute("name").contains(day.toLowerCase())) // since the attribute name contains day, 
                                                                    //so checking like wise according to scenario
        webElement.sendKeys("0");
    else
        webElement.sendKeys("1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to compare `WebElement` with a `currentDay` int. Instead, use the actual input value with the help of `getAttribute()`.

Replace:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("w_1")).equals(currentDay)){
    sun.sendKeys(current_day_zero);
}
else {
    sun.sendKeys(current_day_one);
}
```

with:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.id("w_1").getAttribute('value'));
sun.sendKeys(value == currentDay ? current_day_zero : current_day_one);
```

Comment: @alecex, Its partially working. Now for Wednesday (its 12:20AM), its showing 1, rathrer than 0.